# Make method only callable from unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods, interface

Is it possible to write methods, which are only callable by unit tests? My problem is that our framework contains a lot of `Singleton` classes, which makes unit testing quite hard some time. My idea was to create a simple interface like this:

```
public interface IUnitTestClearable
{
    void ClearForUnitTest();
}
```

This method will be called for "resetting" singleton instances for better handling of unit tests. But this method should only be callable from unit test classes/instances. Is this possible?

Comment: Just remember that private methods can be invoked from outside sources as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a method internal and then set InternalsVisibleTo. This way, you give another assembly access to your internals

http://geekswithblogs.net/jwhitehorn/archive/2007/11/09/116750.aspx

but Tim was just before me as I end this :)

In your project file, AssemblyInfo.cs, set

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Application.Test")]
```

or if you have a signed assembly

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Application.Test, PublicKey=KEYHERE")]
```

Answer (score 5):

Providing access to unit tests while controlling or preventing other things (ab)using that access is a good idea. There are a number of ways this can be done but the simplest is to use `InternalsVisibleTo`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to expose all private methods to your unit tests, as it might cause confusion, so just add a private method for your singleton classes.

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private void ClearForUnitTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cleared.");
    }
}
```

Create extension to be used in your unit tests.

```
public static class PrivateExtensions
{
    public static void ClearForUnitTest<T>(this T instance)
    {
        var method = typeof(T).GetMethod("ClearForUnitTest", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        method.Invoke(instance, null);
    }
}
```

Use like it would be public

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ms = new MySingleton();
    ms.ClearForUnitTest();
}
```

profit